# Python, hard-code it time for filename manipulation

Tags: python, time

I know how to append date to the end of the file name, but I m not sure how can I later in script put that filename as a link to FTP server.

For instance:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
suffix = now.strftime(""%d-%m-%Y, %H:%M"")
filename = 'My history(%s).txt'%suffix
```

How can I hard code it NOW variable so that I can manipulate with it later in script and that time is always the same as it was when it was added to variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to 'hard code' the `now` variable so that it always references the same point of time. The `now()` function from the `datetime` library returns a `datetime` object; the values of the returned object will not change over time.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> x = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> x
datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 14, 16, 26, 6, 592441)
>>> time.sleep(5)
>>> x
datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 14, 16, 26, 6, 592441)
```